Unable to excess the MetaMask Extension page using Selenium with Java
I'm automating a web application that requires authentication via MetaMask. To do this, I initialized the MetaMask extension using ChromeOptions. However, I'm encountering two issues:
When I launch Chrome, it automatically opens the Extension page in a separate tab, but I cannot access it. To work around this, I opened a new tab and loaded it with the Extension URL. When trying to switch to this manually loaded Extension tab, sometimes it navigates properly, but most of the time, it doesn't switch to the tab correctly.
Even if the tab switches to the correct page, I cannot locate any elements or interact with them. I consistently receive the following error:
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error:
Runtime.callFunctionOn threw exception:
Error: LavaMoat - property "Proxy" of globalThis is inaccessible under scuttling mode.
To learn more, visit https://github.com/LavaMoat/LavaMoat/pull/360

I have implemented a wait time to switch between the pages to locate them properly. Additionally, when I retrieved the total number of tabs along with their URLs, I found that there were four windows open in total. Out of these, three were visible, while one was a hidden offscreen page.
